# APK not compatible with newest Android build

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I am working onan app that is currently published on the Play Store.  When using an Android device with version 5.1.1 on it, the play store says "Your device isn't compatible with this versions" and I'm trying to determine the specific reason why and how to work around it.

The existing app's Android.Manifest file has the following in it:

```
  <uses-sdk minSdkVersion="13" targetSdkVersion="21"/>
```

I thought that maybe it was the "targetSDKVersion" causing the problem.  I don't have the APK that was originally published, but I figured I could test my hypothesis by generating a new app with the same uses-sdk manifest items.

I created a new app with the latest Android Studio and the same `uses-sdk` values and published it, and strangely it *is* available on my 5.1.1 device.

I decided to investigate further and I [pulled both APKs down](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apk-downloader/cgihflhdpokeobcfimliamffejfnmfii?hl=en) to my desktop and then used [apktool](http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) to extract the contents of each to see if anything stood out.

What I did find is that the non-working APK has this in the extracted manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.redphx.deviceid" platformBuildVersionCode="21" platformBuildVersionName="5.0.1-1624448">
```

And the working APK has the following

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.opennetcf.ctacke.androidsample" platformBuildVersionCode="23" platformBuildVersionName="6.0-2166767">
```

Right now my assumption is that the `platformBuildVersionCode` must be the culprit.

So my questions are:

1. Is my assumption correct, that this is why one APK is not working for 5.1.1?
2. I assume the APK compiler sets the `platformBuildVersionCode` attribute. I specifically set the `targetSdkVersion` to 21 in the working application, and I see that value in the extracted yml, but the `platformBuildVersionCode` still says 23. Where does that information come from, if not the `uses-sdk` information?
3. Is there a fix, short of rebuilding a new APK and re-publishing?

I assume that re-publishing is the likely route, but I'm hoping to head off having this problem recur in the future, so I'd really like to understand the answers to #1 and #2.

**update**

The merged manifest for the working APK is the same as what is in the application itself, so no reference to 23 at all.

```
<uses-sdk 
    minSdkVersion="13" 
    targetSdkVersion="21"/>
```

On the working system, `build.gradle` contains the following:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.opennetcf.ctacke.androidsample"
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnable false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile filetree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

So I assume that this is where that info comes from, but how it gets to the APK still isn't all that clear.

I don't have either for the non-working APK since it was built by the app release team before I came on the project and I have no idea if they keep any of these intermediate outputs.  I'm investigating that.

**edit 2**

The extracted yml from both APKs (which shows the `uses-sdk` info) is below.  It looks like the non-working minimum version is significatly lower (5) than the working (13).

working:

```
version: 2.0.1
apkFileName: oncf.apk
isFrameworkApk: false
usesFramework:
  ids:
  - 1
sdkInfo:
  minSdkVersion: '13'
  targetSdkVersion: '21'
packageInfo:
  forced-package-id: '127'
versionInfo:
  versionCode: '1'
  versionName: '1.0'
compressionType: false
sharedLibrary: false
```

non-working:

```
version: 2.0.1
apkFileName: ytb.apk
isFrameworkApk: false
usesFramework:
  ids:
  - 1
sdkInfo:
  minSdkVersion: '5'
  targetSdkVersion: '21'
packageInfo:
  forced-package-id: '127'
versionInfo:
  versionCode: '4'
  versionName: 1.1.2
compressionType: false
sharedLibrary: false
```

Comment: "The existing app's Android.Manifest file has the following in it" -- what is in the `build.gradle` file? What is in the merged manifest, from your `app/build/intermediates/manifests/` directory?

Comment: @CommonsWare: updated the question to include that info

Comment: What is the `android:minSdkVersion` in your extracted manifest for the non-working APK? I am assuming that the line you show in your question is from the input manifest (i.e., the one in the project itself).

Comment: Yes, the line is from the input.  The extracted yml shows that the non-working minimum is 5, while the working minimum is 13.

Comment: I have no idea what `platformBuildVersionCode` or where it comes from. You might try installing the non-working APK from the command line (`adb install path/to/your.apk`) and see what the error message is there, as it could be that we're misinterpreting what the Play Store is telling you.

Comment: Please give us the rest of your build.gradle information, the buildToolsVersion, and everything else from that file.

Comment: @Stephan: ammended above

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a very specific reason for doing it, your `targetSdkVersion` needs to match your `compileSdkVersion`

Also, you'll need to increment the `versionCode` (I can see this was done in the published apk, but this wasn't done in the rest of the build.gradle file you just gave us)

If your original manifest file still contains the `minSdkVersion` and the `targetSdkVersion` attributes, you can delete those. Those two attributes will now be coming from your `build.gradle` file to create the intermediary manifest. This is the new way Android is doing it.

Also, your `proguard-rules.pro` reference is missing a single quote on its right. I assume this must be some kind of cutting and pasting error.